# How do you configure a WCF service with two endpoints to use a different ListenUri for each endpoint?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, basichttpbinding, webhttpbinding

I have a WCF Service which exposes an endpoint using the `webHttpBinding` and is consumed by both WPF and ASP.NET applications.  Everything works great.

I am now attempting to consume the service from Windows Phone (WP7).  However, as the .NET Framework hasn't quite caught up to WP7 yet, the `System.ServiceModel.Web` namespace is unavailable with the result that the `webHttpBinding` doesn't work in WP7.

Now, on my service, if I switch the `webHttpBinding` out for a `basicHttpBinding`, the phone application works.

I do not want to have to rework my WPF and ASP.NET applications to use the `basicHttpBinding` though.

I understand that WCF is capable of supporting multiple bindings and I have attempted to configure and run the service so that it exposes endpoints for both `webHttpBinding` and `basicHttpBinding`.  The service appears to start up fine.  However, the WPF & ASP.NET applications are unable to access it.  And when I attempt to create a Service Reference in the WP7 application I get the following message:

> A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI
>   'http://localhost:1726/GeneralService.svc'. If two endpoints want to
>   share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object
>   instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in
>   AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of
>   AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

A colleague and I have played around with a variety of changes to the `baseAddress`, `address`, and `listenUri` attributes without any luck.  We are now at the point of just trial and error which isn't proving to be very effective.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="generalBasic" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="general" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="MyProject.GeneralService">
            <endpoint address="mex" 
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <endpoint address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="generalBasic"
                contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
            <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" 
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="general" 
                contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1726/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Just specify the address attribute with a value for either basic or webhttp endpoint that would distinguish its address. Ex: <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web"  address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding"                 bindingConfiguration="general"                  contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" /> should resolve your problem

Comment: hmm... funny, I had tried this previously but it didn't work.  (perhaps I added set the address attribute of my basicHttpBinding rather than my webHttpBinding).  this time though, as you suggested, i set the address attribute of my webHttpBinding and the WP7 app connected fine.  after appending the new value to the address attributes on my WPF & MVC client apps, everything seems to be working like a charm.  Post your comment as an answer and I'll give it to you.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just specify the address attribute with a value for either basic or webhttp endpoint that would distinguish its address. Ex:

```
<endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="general" contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
```

should resolve your problem

Comment: @CoffeeAddict The content type determines if you response is in Json or XML. The address attribute is to distinguish each endpoint on which binding it uses and 2 endpoints cannot have the same address

Comment: Does that mean when you want to send a request, you have to post your request to the address with .svc/web as suffix or you can still use .svc address?

Answer (score 3):

When defining your endpoints for the first one you are specifying `address=""` and for second you dont have any value(So even for this one we will have address as `""`)

```
<endpoint address="" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="generalBasic"
            contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" 
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="general" 
            contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
```

So in that case when we specify address as empty it will take default base address.

So try to specify some value for anyone of the endpoints. So that we will have different address for these 2 endpoints.

```
<endpoint address="" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="generalBasic"
            contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" address="WP7Service" 
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="general" 
            contract="MyProject.Contracts.IGeneralService" />
```

So our new endpoints address are:

1. http://localhost:1726/GeneralService.svc
2. http://localhost:1726/GeneralService.svc/WP7Service

Comment: I've done it without putting an address when getting it work for json

Comment: but then yea to distinguish xml vs. a json endpoint you have to freakin put in a stupid address attribute rather than it being able to just figure it out via content-type in the request.  So basically if you don't hack WCF to check the content-type in the request and do your own custom code while  intercepting the call, you can't hvae both xml and json endpoints for REST out there.  Or you have to put a /json/ in the url and specify one with the address="json" for you to be able to provide json and xml endoints in WCF I guesss.

Answer (score 0):

For usage service on WP you should expose your service with Rest, Soap or OData endpoints. In the link below it is quite clear described how to expose WCF RIA for such purposes: 
[Exposing WCF (SOAP\WSDL) Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/29/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-wcf-wsdl-services.aspx)

It works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was `protocolMapping` for both endpoints:

```
<configuration>
  <!--...-->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--...-->
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBindingConfiguration"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" />
        <binding name="SecureHttpBindingConfiguration" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Namespace.ServiceName">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration"
          contract="Namespace.IServiceName" />
      </service>
      <service name="Namespace.ServiceName">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBindingConfiguration"
          contract="Namespace.IServiceName" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <!--...-->
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!--...-->
</configuration>
```